# Keep getting the Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : factor subj has new levels

Tags: r, regression

[image: example of my data]

I'm trying to make a linear regression based on hr data. I  keep getting the error that my factor subj has new levels.

Im super new to r so I apologize if I  made any obvious mistakes! Thank you in advance I'm  really lost and desperate.

Here is the code i  used to do so. Dat is what my data frame name is called and commons and techs refers to other columns that are similar to CloseFriendsG1.

```
commons<-grep("^C",rownames(dat),value=TRUE)
type_q=rep("Common",dim(dat)[1])
type_q[techs]="Technical"
dat$totals<-rowSums(dat[,techs])+rowSums(dat[,commons])
head(dat)
set.seed(2016)
Train=sample(1:156,110,replace=FALSE)
ModTrain<-lm(totals~.,data=dat[Train,])
ModTest<-predict(ModTrain,newdata=dat[-Train,])``
```

Comment: You implement `subj` as a predictor. Drop `subj` from your data frame.

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit of explanation, your column `id` is most likely a unique entry, and when you do `totals~.` , you are regressing against all columns other than `totals`. If there is only one observation per `id` factor, it cannot be estimated and the regression is.. quite nonsense:

```
da = data.frame(id=factor(1:10),x=runif(10),y=runif(10),z=runif(10))
trn = 1:5
mod = lm(y ~ .,data=da[trn,])

summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = da[trn, ])

Residuals:
ALL 5 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.48208         NA      NA       NA
id2          0.11749         NA      NA       NA
id3          0.01146         NA      NA       NA
id4         -0.29586         NA      NA       NA
id5          0.34529         NA      NA       NA
x                 NA         NA      NA       NA
z                 NA         NA      NA       NA
```

You can remove it while doing the model fitting:

```
mod = lm(y ~ .,data=da[trn,-1])
predict(mod,da[-trn,])
        6         7         8         9        10 
0.2992070 1.2727160 0.7789787 0.6585381 0.4227041
```

For your example, use `lm(totals~.,data=dat[Train,-1])` or `lm(totals~.,data=dat[Train,!grepl("subj",colname(dat))])`. it doesn't matter if the id is in the data.frame for prediction.